# Changing Country Market while updating a .xap on the store

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store, xap

I've got an application that targets three countries on the market. I would like to update the  xap of the application but just for one country.
The two others coutries will keep the old version of the app. Is this possible ? (I'm talking about the market distribution not the language of the app)

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If the single .xap file is uploaded for three different country then you will never be able to update .xap file for only one country.